# React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs

React Hook is not working, giving error as attached screenshot:-
[image]

My Code:-

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

import WEBINAR_LIST from './webinar_data';

const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0); //create page state

const pageData = useMemo(() => {

     return WEBINAR_LIST.slice(page*5, (page*5)+5)
},[page])

const nextPage = () => setPage(prev => prev+1)
const prevPage = () => setPage(prev => prev > 0 ? prev-1 : prev)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call React Hooks at top level, you will need to create a functional component.

Learn more about compontents [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) and about hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

A functional component looks something like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Create your functional component:
function Example() {
  // And now you can use hooks
  // But only inside your functional component's
  // body
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: No you aren't, you are writing your code in top level. Please refer to the link I gave you and looked at example of a functional component I wrote in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, actually I was using my code outside of functions...

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

In other words you most likely need to move your const below your main function.  For me i had to move my const with useState below export function App.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useState hook like this at top level

```
import { useState } from "react"

const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0) // it should not be initilize here

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div>Example</div>
  )
}
```

You should use it like below example

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Example() {
  
    const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0) //use state should be inside function
  
    return (
    <div>Example</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the existing answers?